# "Each woven from the fabric of values" What it means?

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, metaphors, structure

> Culture wears many different hats, each woven from the fabric of values.

In the above sentence, "the pharase woven from the fabric of values" means what? What is its gramartical position?

Thans in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "woven from the fabric of values" is an adjectival phrase, describing some characteristic of the "hats" of the main clause. "Each" is referencing "hats" as an antecedent, so "(each hat) is (woven from the fabric of values)", just as something might be "woven of silk" ('woven' is an adjective to describe something made by *weaving*).

Like everything else in the sentence, it is metaphorical. You may have come across the idiom "to wear many hats" before; it means to have a variety of roles, of different capacities in which you may be acting. This extends the metaphor, suggesting that culture has a range of roles or identities ('different hats'), and then further identifying that these hats are "woven from the fabric of values".

It's not a great metaphor, because you don't make hats by weaving, and weaving doesn't use fabric - it makes it. But what the overall metaphor is saying is, I believe, that the different identities or roles that culture takes up are, in themselves, made up of values - things culture, or wider society, holds to be important.